# Intel 852GME driver

Tags: 10.04, intel-graphics, intel, cinnamon

**UPDATE 1:**

So just to finalise the question/answer, it is not possible for me to install the correct drivers for my laptop on Ubuntu 10.04.  I will have to wait for Ubuntu 12.04 if I want to stick with LTS releases?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have a Toshiba Satellite Pro A40:

```
CPU: Mobile Intel Pentium 4 3.0GHz
RAM: 2Gb
HDD: 80Gb
GPU: Intel 852GME
```

To install Ubuntu 10.04.3, I had to enter `i915.modeset=0 xforcevesa` just to get started.  This has allowed me to successfully install 10.04.3, but I don't seem to have any graphics acceleration.

So my question is, are there any drivers available for Ubuntu for the Intel 852GME chipset?  I would like to try out Unity (not Unity2D) which I can't do at the moment

Comment: Please see update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have this graphics card in my office notebook and tried to use 10.04 on it.The version provided in 10.04 LTS does not support this cards.From 10.10 on the card should work properly with the drivers ubuntu offers.

I suggest in this case to install 11.10 although I also usually prefere the LTS versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: sorry, indeed 11.10. However, you will also be able to upgrade to 12.04 from 11.10 i guess.

Comment: Please see update.